# React Native Render Error: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEk5Z.png)I get this error on the android simulator phone I am using, my VS code shows no errors. I followed a tutorial and I have the same code as the youtuber but his works and mine doesnt.

I was expecting Tab Buttons to show on the bottom of the screen with my predefined 'screens'

Here's the video im watching if that helps, im around minute 45 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hb9FJ5D6jh0&list=PLHQY5AFuyYYUtJiw8R92rHAYha0sTJT1Z

Comment: What the screen name you are using in navigate method?
Can you attach code also for navigation method call?